# Wordpress Woocommerce cart scripts enqeue for shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, overriding

I'm trying to figure out how to load the cart.min.js scripts **not only** if `IS_CART` but **also** if `SHORTCODE_EXISTS('woocommrece_cart')`, I can see that all the fronted scripts enqueues are in `class-wc-frontend-scripts.php` file and I don't want to override it, is there any hook that I can use to add another IF statement to the same file?

THANKS :)

---

after some testing 
I want to explain my problem again:

- I have a 'woocommerce_cart' shortcode that doesn't loads the scripts that it needs to work via ajax (like when updating cart and etc...) on other pages than the cart page
- I see that in the class-wc-frontend-scripts.php the enqueue of that script goes only when is_cart() statement.
- I am figuring out that I need to add if(shortcode_exists('woccommerce_cart')) so it would enqueue also when it is a shortcode.
- I am adding that IF and I see that everything works on front end.
- I am thinking that it is not a good idea to put that in the original plugin file because it would be overwritten with the next update.
- I am trying to enqueue the script in my functions.php file with the new IF.
- Nothing works....
- Going back to the original file
- On line 247 (here: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php) there is a function that adds more functionality to the ajax that without it it wont work...
- Now I am wondering is there a way to add another IF to the same file using a hook? Or should I override all the file? (as I said before I think it is not a good practice because all the functions there wont get any updates).
- So basically I know what I need to do, I just don't know what is the best way to do it and if it possible doing it with a hook or other function that maybe somebody knows and I'm not familiar with....

Thank you again for your help! :)

---

Comment: Hi there, can you maybe copy your code here.

Answer (score 1):

### SHORT ANSWER

You need to define the WOOCOMMERCE_CART constant and make sure you're using a modern version of Woocommerce. I've tested this solution in Woocomerce 3.0.7.

```
if (!defined('WOOCOMMERCE_CART')) define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CART', TRUE );
```

### LONG ANSWER

I was having the same problem:
 - I was calling the [woocommerce_cart] shortcode with the do_shortcode() function to display the cart in all the pages of my site.
 - The cart was displaying well but the scripts (specifically cart.min.js) weren't loading in the pages. The effect of this is that the AJAX interactions weren't working.

The pages in my site were already running WC_Frontend_Scripts::init(). This function calls WC_Frontend_Scripts::load_scripts and that function loads our cart.min.js only if is_cart() (file wc-conditional-functions.php) is TRUE, as you already pointed.
Now, the current version of is_cart() evaluates TRUE when any of the following conditions is TRUE:

- `is_page( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) )`
- `defined( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CART' )`
- `wc_post_content_has_shortcode( 'woocommerce_cart' )`

So, for me, the easiest way to fix the problem was to define the WOOCOMMERCE_CART constant.

Hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, combining cart and checkout pages broke the ajax auto cart
updates. I add the cart to the checkout page using:

```
  function cart_on_checkout_page() 
  {
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return;
    echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]');
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'cart_on_checkout_page', 5 );
```

My solution was to use the following code in functions.php to check if we are on the checkout page, and if so, enqueue/load the 'wc-cart' script. It's working with Woocommerce version 4.5.2.

```
function adjust_woocommerce_scripts() 
{ 
  if ( is_checkout() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-cart' ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adjust_woocommerce_scripts', 11 );
```

You can adjust this function to perform whatever checks you need, such as if SHORTCODE_EXISTS('woocommrece_cart') - this means that the 'wc-cart' script is only loaded on the pages you need.